# SU(N) covariant derivatives

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is there any book or paper that discusses the differential operators corresponding to $SU(N)$ $(N=4,5,...)$ covariant derivatives in details? At least for the case of $N=4,$ the explicit form is of high importance in my work. Recall that these covarinat derivatives basically correspond to generators of the $SU(N)$ right (left) rotations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Do you want the expressions for the left (resp. right) invariant vector fields on the $SU(N)$ manifold?

Comment: As you are a physicist, I give you the following example. Suppose you want to define topological charge operator on $CP^1$ manifold. To do so, one identifies the $R_{\pm}:=R_1\pm iR_2$ of the $SU(2)$ right rotations as some well-known operators in terms of derivatives wrt coordinates on any given patch of $CP^1$. Then $[R_{+},R_{-}]\Psi=n\Psi$ where $\Psi$ is a line section on the patch. (Take QHE example, and $n$ becomes the monopole charge and etc.). I'm looking for these generators on the $SU(N)$ manifold specially the case $N=4.$

Comment: But in your example what you have are differential operators on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ not on the the 3-sphere.  So do you want differential operators on $SU(N)$ or on some other manifold on which $SU(N)$ acts transitively, e.g., $\mathbb{C}P^{N-1}$?

Comment: As I said, I want differential operators on $SU(N)$. I already have the differential operators on the coset space, which is a Grassmanian (thus Kahlarian)!